# IE 10 HTTP 401 Error on ajax POST

Tags: ajax, iis-7, http-post, internet-explorer-10, http-status-code-401

[I've been chasing down an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210158/401-using-multiple-authentication-methods-ie-10-only) and decided to make the most basic reproduction of the issue possible in hopes that a simplified question will help me resolve this.

I am receiving a 401 when posting to a web service via ajax in javascript. I will include as much information as well as all of the troubleshooting steps I have tried.

I created a test page on the root of my site and tried both plain JS and jquery for the ajax call with the same results. I've included the jquery commented out...

**Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var ID = 2;
        var firstname = $('#First_Name').val();
        var lastname = $('#Last_Name').val(); 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/service/name/service.aspx/ChangeName',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{ "ID": "' + ID + '", "firstName": "' + firstname + '", "lastName": "' + lastname + '" }',
            success: function() {
                console.log('success');

            },
            error: function(d) {
                console.log(d.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});*/

function runAjax() {
    //Create Http request depending on browser
    var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
      }

    // Function to create 
    var url = "/service/name/service.aspx/ChangeName";
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    var data=JSON.stringify({ "ID": "2", "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" });
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="34%">
                <div align="right">
                    <strong>First Name: </strong>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <input name="First_Name" type="text"id="First_Name" size="20">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div align="right">
                    <strong>Last Name: </strong>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Last_Name" type="text" id="Last_Name" size="20">
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>

      <div align="center">

        <input id="button" type="button" value="Update Student Details" onclick="runAjax();" style="margin:5px;">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in every browser except for IE10 this works fine. In fiddler it shows that IE is getting a 401 response

**Request Headers** *fiddler*

```
POST http://dev.mysite/service/name/service.aspx/ChangeName HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://dev.mysite/test_page.html
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 46
DNT: 1
Host: dev.mysite
Pragma: no-cache

{"ID":"2","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

**Response Headers** *fiddler*

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
jsonerror: true
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2013 01:12:05 GMT
Content-Length: 105
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

I enabled Failed Request Tracing on the server and this is the information it gives me for that call:

**Failed Request Log** *iis*

**1. -GENERAL_REQUEST_START**

- *SiteId* - 2
- *AppPoolId* - ASP.NET v4.0
- *ConnId* - 1610622306
- *RawConnId* - 0
- *RequestURL* - http://dev.mysite:80/service/name/service.aspx/ChangeName
- *RequestVerb* - POST

**2. -FILTER_START**

- *FilterName* - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll

**3. -FILTER_END**

**4. -AspNetStart**

- *ConnID* - 0
- *Context ID* - {00000000-0000-0000-6425-0080000000BF}
- *Data1* - POST
- *Data2* - /service/name/service.aspx
- *Data3* -

**5. -GENERAL_REQUEST_END**

- *BytesSent* - 359
- *BytesReceived* - 440
- *HttpStatus* - 401
- *HttpSubStatus* - 0

Things I found by simplifying the ajax request was that it is not only a Windows 8 problem and that turning compatibility mode on does not work either.

I have tried disabling the Kernel-mode authentication in IIS, I've triple checked permissions on the web service folder, [followed these suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/484657/401-using-multiple-authentication-methods-ie-10-only/484677?noredirect=1#484677), I've even tried placing the web service in the same directory as the page. All with the same result... Any direction or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I came upon it because I was having a similar problem.  This is what worked for me, however - once I added this to web.config I stopped getting the 401 error:

```
<webservices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"></add>
        <add name="HttpPost"></add>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious if it's the same issue I had.

Does adding a slash at the end of your URL fix the issue in IE 10? e.g.

```
/service/name/service.aspx/ChangeName/
```

instead of

```
/service/name/service.aspx/ChangeName
```

If so then Eric Lawrence of Fiddler and IE fame explains it here, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx